# Part of the uiview doesn't call touchesBegan for view on top of uisplitview

Tags: ipad, touchesbegan, uisplitview

I'm writting an ipad app with a uisplitview. Once a user taps on a button, I display another view in full screen by removing the uisplitview from the stack and pushing the new view.  The problem I have is that the new uiview only gets touchesBegan for 3/4 of the screen.  It seems like that is the same area used up for the uidetailview in the uisplitview.  I've been trying to figure this out for a few days with no luck.

the uisplitview gets synthesized and it gets added in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions like this:

[window addSubview:splitViewController.view];

[window makeKeyAndVisible];

then, when the user touches a button, I do this:

NewViewController *newViewController = [NewViewController alloc];

UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:newViewController];

navController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
navController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;

[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];

[newViewController release];

[navController release];

Answer (score 0):

Check the sizes of the bounds of the view. It should be as big as the iPad screen. That is 1024x768 (or 768x1024).

Comment: I will check that once I get to my computer.  Thanks

Comment: The view was 748 X 1024, but after I increased the size I still don't get touches.

Comment: Even if the size was 748 X 1024, I only get touches for 3/4 of the screen.  The simulator is in portrait mode and from the top to 3/4, I get touches, for the last 1/4 of the screen, the touchesBegan doesn't get called at all.

Comment: Could you post some code about where the uisplitview is generated and how it is switched with the new view?

Answer (score 0):

Long time ago... but maybe somebody else needs the answer. I had the same problem. My fault was that I initialized the UIWindow with portrait mode (1024+768) but this is wrong. The window, however you rotate the iPad, will never rotate and must have the portrait dimensions (768x1024).